# Contact list as dictionary

Tags: macros, lists

#### Introduction

I am trying to create a template to make it easier to type problemsets and exams for the university I am working for. In that regard it is often neccecary to write down the contact information of the members of the faculty.

What I am looking for is a **user friendly** way to insert people into a "dictionary" and retrieve them using some ID.

Something like the following would ideal

#### Example

```
\updateContactInfo{
    \addMember{
        id = joe,
        name = Joe Doe,
        mobile = 12345678,
        phone = 87654321
    }
    \addMember{
        id = jane,
        name = Jane Doe,
        mobile = 12345678,
        phone = 87654321
    }
}

\begin{document}

\getContactInfo[jane][name]

\end{document}
```

Here is what I have so far, but the code is not ideal. The syntax is hard to read and update for the normal user

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse,xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand\contactInfo{m m}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {jane}{%
        \IfStrEqCase{#2}{%
            {name}{Jane Doe}
            {mobile}{32132132}
            {phone}{123123123}
            }[]
        }
        {Joe}{%       
        \IfStrEqCase{#2}{%
            {name}{Joe Doe}
            {mobile}{32132132}
            {phone}{123123123}
            }[]
        }
        {richard}{%
        \IfStrEqCase{#2}{%
            {name}{Richard Roe}
            {mobile}{32132132}
            {phone}{123123123}
            }[]
        }%
        }[]
}

\begin{document}

\contactInfo{jane}{mobile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. KOMA-Script already has such functionality. See the manual page 232 and 271. You ought to look at Nicola Talbot's [probsoln](https://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln) and the affiliated programs [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) and the frontend [datatooltk](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk), which seems to do what you are aiming at.

Comment: Using a KOMA-script seems like shooting a small bird with a penguin. Similarly with the datatool packages. My needs are much simpler, max 3-4 values for the tables. However, if you want to post an answer using the packages aforementioned feel free to do so =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate storing contact info and retrieving it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineInfo}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_nebu_contact_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_nebu_contact_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\contactInfo}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {phone}  { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { g_nebu_contact_#1_prop } { #2 } } }
    {mobile} { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { g_nebu_contact_#1_prop } { #2 } } }
   }
   { \prop_item:cn { g_nebu_contact_#1_prop } { #2 } }
 }

%%% formatting phone numbers
\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebu_phone:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=45123123,
}
\defineInfo{joe}{
  name=Joe Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=93123123,
}
\defineInfo{richard}{
  name=Richard Roe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=83123123,
}

\begin{document}

\contactInfo{jane}{name} has \contactInfo{jane}{mobile} mobile phone.

\contactInfo{richard}{phone} is \contactInfo{richard}{name}'s phone.

\end{document}
```

I also added the support for printing phone numbers as described in a previous answer of mine.

The idea is to use a property list for each contact. With `\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn` it's possible to have an easy interface for input.

[image]

With the following version, the contact key becomes case insensitive:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineInfo}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\contactInfo}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {phone}  { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
    {mobile} { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
   }
   { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_contact_prop:n
 {
  g_nebu_contact_\str_lowercase:n { #1 }_prop
 }

%%% formatting phone numbers
\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebu_phone:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=45123123,
}
\defineInfo{joe}{
  name=Joe Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=93123123,
}
\defineInfo{richard}{
  name=Richard Roe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=83123123,
}

\begin{document}

\contactInfo{Jane}{name} has \contactInfo{jane}{mobile} mobile phone.

\contactInfo{riCHard}{phone} is \contactInfo{Richard}{name}'s phone.

\end{document}
```

A version that might be compatible with TeX Live 2017; I can't recommend using Overleaf, because it lags very much behind.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineInfo}{mm}
 {
  \prop_new:c { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } }
  \prop_clear:N \l__nebu_contact_tmp_prop
  \keys_set:nn { nebu/contact } { #2 }
  \prop_gset_eq:cN { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } \l__nebu_contact_tmp_prop
 }
\keys_define:nn { nebu/contact }
 {
  unknown .code:n = \prop_put:NVn \l__nebu_contact_tmp_prop \l_keys_key_tl { #1 }
 }
\prop_new:N \l__nebu_contact_tmp_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { NV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\contactInfo}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {phone}  { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
    {mobile} { \nebu_phone:e { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } } }
   }
   { \prop_item:cn { \__nebu_contact_prop:n { #1 } } { #2 } }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_contact_prop:n
 {
  g_nebu_contact_\str_lowercase:n { #1 }_prop
 }

%%% formatting phone numbers
\NewDocumentCommand{\phone}{m}
 {
  \nebu_phone:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nebu_phone_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nebu_phone:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l__nebu_phone_tl { ~ }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__nebu_phone_tl = 8 }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_eight:V \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__nebu_phone_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebu_phone:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {4}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {8}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
    {9}{ \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn #1 }
   }
   {
    \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nebu_phone_eight:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_iii_ii_iii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2#3\nobreakspace#4#5\nobreakspace#6#7#8 }
\cs_new:Nn \__nebu_phone_ii:nnnnnnnn { #1#2\nobreakspace#3#4\nobreakspace#5#6\nobreakspace#7#8 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineInfo{jane}{
  name=Jane Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=45123123,
}
\defineInfo{joe}{
  name=Joe Doe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=93123123,
}
\defineInfo{richard}{
  name=Richard Roe,
  mobile=32132132,
  phone=83123123,
}

\begin{document}

\contactInfo{Jane}{name} has \contactInfo{jane}{mobile} mobile phone.

\contactInfo{riCHard}{phone} is \contactInfo{Richard}{name}'s phone.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, what a quick answer! Is it possible to make the key search case insensitive? I tried looking at a few other answers, but was not able to find an easy solution.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Easy enough, with `expl3`. `:-)` See edit.

Comment: Hmm, I can not seem to make the code work. Any idea why? I keep getting the following error message: `\__nebu_contact_prop:` not defined. See https://i.imgur.com/p4tFeMf.png

Comment: Seems like I am using `TeX Live 2017` is it possible to make it work for that version? It works just fine when I compile it locally, but I need it to also work in Overleaf (which uses a two year old distribution...)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Sorry. Complain with Overleaf.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I added a version that should run also on TeX Live 2017; anyway, I consider a very bad service from Overleaf to lag so much behind.

Comment: Thanks a million for the new version you truly are an lifesaver. I will clean up the messages tomorrow.  With the new version I am down to one error: `! Undefined control sequence. \exp_args:Ne ->\::e`. However,  I can not see this feature being used anywhere. Here is the complete error logfie: https://pastebin.com/W0s9YdhV